# Função .click sendo executada duas vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

tenho uma função $(".btn-comprar").click() que, quando clico, ela é executada duas vezes. Não consigo resolver o problema. Já pesquisei o código todo e ela não tem duplicidade. O que pode ser?

Função:

```js
$(".btn-comprar").click(function () {
        var produto = {};
        produto.nome = $(this).parent().find('h3').text();
        produto.valor = $(this).parent().find('.preco').text();
        produto.quantidade = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
        produto.id = $(this).parent().find('input').attr('data-button');
        if (sessionStorage) {
            var cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
            cart.produtos.push(produto);
            $(".numCart").text(cart.produtos.length);
            sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
            alert('Produto adicionado ao carrinho.');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='btn btn-comprar' href='javascript:'>Comprar</a>
```

Comment: Verifique se a classe .btn-comprar esta sendo usada em outros elementos.

Comment: Existem outros elementos que utilizam a classe, pois se trata de um botão de compra, comum a todos produtos da página. Mas só é executada quando o usuário dá o click.

Comment: Tente colocar o e.preventDefault(); antes do var produto = {};

Answer (score 3):

Esse tipo de comportamento geralmente ocorre por duas razões:

## 1. Evento se aplica a dois elementos na mesma hierarquia

Problema: você adicionou um manipulador de evento que se aplica a mais de um elemento, sendo que um deles é descendente do outro. Ao clicar, o navegador propaga o evento para os dois elementos e assim o manipulador executa duas vezes.

Exemplo:

```html
<div class="botao"><button class="botao">Ação</button></div>
```

```js
$('.botao').click(...)
```

Solução:

1. Use o [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) dentro da função para que o evento não seja propagado para o segundo elemento.
2. Garante que o manipulador só captura o evento para um dos elementos

## 2. O código que adiciona o evento executa duas vezes

Problema: um código adiciona uma função para manipular um evento, mas por alguma razão esse código executa duas vezes. Isso pode ocorrer por vários motivos.

Um deles ocorre quando se adiciona um manipulador de eventos genérico após criar um elemento dinamicamente. Exemplo:

```js
$('<button class="botao">').appendTo(body);
$('.botao').click(...)
```

Na primeira vez que o código executa, o manipulador do evento clique é corretamente adicionado. Mas, da segunda vez, os botões já existentes vão receber um manipulador adicional.

Solução:

1. Adicione um manipulador específico, apenas para o novo elemento criado.
2. Adicione uma única vez um manipulador geral usando [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Exemplo:
   `$('.local-com-botoes').on('click', '.botao', ...);`

No exemplo acima, todos os botões com a classe `botao` adicionados dinamicamente a um elemento com a classe `local-com-botoes` irão disparar o manipulador de eventos.

Outras razões para um script executar duas vezes são mais óbvias:

- Incluir o script duas vezes na página
- Chamar a função que cria o evento mais de uma vez de lugares diferentes

Dica: coloque um log na função que adiciona o manipulador de eventos e verifique se ele executa apenas uma vez.